# How to install Ubuntu 12.10 in window xp with fedora already installed?

Tags: installation

I am using window xp and Fedora. Now I want to use Ubuntu 12.10 instead of Fedora. Can anyone please help me how to install Ubuntu 12.10 by overriding Fedora and without affecting existing Windows OS. In other words how to replace Fedora with Ubuntu without affecting windows xp.

Thanks, 
Chetan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Burn the Ubuntu ISO to a DVD. Reboot with the DVD in the system. Choose "install Ubuntu", answer all the questions and 1 of those questions will be about partitioning. Choose manual, select and delete the partition(s) Fedora is on tell it to mount / and any other partitions you want.

What you also can do is from within Windows XP is to remove the partitions Fedora is on and not allocate those partitions (delete them but do not format them). During install you can then choose to install Ubuntu onto the unallocated space.

These are the 2 simplest options.